# how to disable current day in jquery datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My code is:

```
$('#eventDatePicker').datetimepicker({
        timepicker : false,
        format : 'd.m.Y',
        minDate : 0
    });
```

how to disable current day in showing date picker

Comment: So all other possible dates should be valid, just not the current day?

Comment: maybe you want to set dates greater than today? then you have to use the mindate option
http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate